# using Google Script to get attachment from Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-sheets-api

So I built a spreadsheet that gets 2 reports from 2 different sources and then imports them into the sheet. One of the reports is a CSV file that is sent to my email every hour.

The script I have works....mostly. It will check my email for the thread, pull the message, and then import the attachment to the sheet. The problem is when the next email is received the next hour and the script runs again, it won't pull the most recent attachment, it will only pull the first one. I've even tried moving the message to my trash every time it runs, but it still will pull it from the trash. Here is my code.

```
function importReport() {

  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox from:"system@Report.com"');
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  attachment.setContentType('text/csv');

 // Is the attachment a CSV file
 if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RawReport");
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

  // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
   sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
   sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

 GmailApp.moveMessageToTrash(message);
  }


}
```

The goal is for it to pull the whole thread and then import the most recent attachment, any advice?

Comment: You complained that it was pulling from trash, you can check this with: `message.isInTrash();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try pulling the last message from the Gmail thread instead of the first message.

```
var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
var message = messages[messages.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

So thanks to user @AmitAgarwal the fix was as follows.

```
//download the thread with all the attachments (they will build up over time)
   var message = threads[0].getMessages(); 
  //Get the most recent attachment
  var attachment = message[message.length - 1].getAttachments()[0];
```

This will download the whole thread, and get the most recent attachment.

An alternate solution that i came upon is to reverse the array after you pull it.

```
var message = threads[0].getMessages();
message.reverse();
var attachment = message[0].getAttachments()[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * Note:
 * http://www.googleappsscript.org/home/fetch-gmail-attachment-to-google-drive-using-google-apps-script#TOC-Installation-notes
 * If you need any paid assistant, please write to support.waqar@gmail.com
 * We provide Apps Script Development services at very reasonable price.
 */

// GLOBALS
//Array of file extension which you would like to extract to Drive
var fileTypesToExtract = ['jpg', 'tif', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg'];
//Name of the folder in google drive i which files will be put
var folderName = 'Gmail To Drive';
//Name of the label which will be applied after processing the mail message
var labelName = '@indrive';



function GmailToDrive(){
  //build query to search emails
  var query = '';
  //filename:jpg OR filename:tif OR filename:gif OR fileName:png OR filename:bmp OR filename:svg'; //'after:'+getDateNDaysBack_(1)+
  for(var i in fileTypesToExtract){
    query += (query === '' ?('filename:'+fileTypesToExtract[i]) : (' OR filename:'+fileTypesToExtract[i]));
  }
  query = 'in:inbox has:nouserlabels ' + query;
//  query += ' after:'+getDateNDaysBack_(1);
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var label = getGmailLabel_(labelName);
  var parentFolder;
  if(threads.length > 0){
    parentFolder = getFolder_(folderName);
  }
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  for(var i in threads){
    var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
    for(var j in mesgs){
      //get attachments
      var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
      for(var k in attachments){
        var attachment = attachments[k];
//      var isDefinedType = checkIfDefinedType_(attachment);
//      if(!isDefinedType) continue;
        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
        parentFolder.addFile(file);
        root.removeFile(file);
      }
    }
    threads[i].addLabel(label);
  }
}

//This function will get the parent folder in Google drive
function getFolder_(folderName){
  var folder;
  var fi = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  if(fi.hasNext()){
    folder = fi.next();
  }
  else{
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
  }
  return folder;
}

//getDate n days back
// n must be integer
function getDateNDaysBack_(n){
  n = parseInt(n);
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - n);
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy/MM/dd');
}

function getGmailLabel_(name){
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name);
  if(!label){
    label = GmailApp.createLabel(name);
  }
  return label;
}

//this function will check for filextension type.
// and return boolean
function checkIfDefinedType_(attachment){
  var fileName = attachment.getName();
  var temp = fileName.split('.');
  var fileExtension = temp[temp.length-1].toLowerCase();
  if(fileTypesToExtract.indexOf(fileExtension) !== -1) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Now Simple add any trigger to test.Attachments will be seen easily in google Drive

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer. @Muhammad Bilal.